# PySpark: How to join two tables on different keys AND get all columns from each?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to join two dataframes in pyspark but I cannot get the second dataframe's columns to show up in the result:

```
df_a.withColumn("loc", f.col("ORIGIN")).join(df_b.withColumn("loc", f.col("call2")), on="loc")\
.select([x for x in df_a.columns] + [x for x in df_b.columns])
```

If I manually specify each column, it will work, but its tedious:

```
df_a.withColumn("loc", f.col("ORIGIN")).join(df_b.withColumn("loc", f.col("call2")), on="loc")\
.select([x for x in df_a.columns] + ['latitude'] + ['longitude'] + etc....)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide more code and preferably a minimal reproducer. What does df_a and df_b look like, what output do you expect, and what output did you actually obtain?

Comment: You can also try doing `df_a.join(df_b, df_a.ORIGIN == df_b.call2).select('*')`

Comment: Thanks -- I had a slight error!